# Whats the right name for fixed position files?

Tags: data-structures, csv

You can structure data in various ways: for example comma separated or tab separated.

But you can also structure data on positions. So, for example, the first 20 characters are meant for a phone number, the following 2 characters are meant for the age of someone etc...

How would you call such a file in general?

Comment: These are called `fixed width`. Some call these flat file databases -  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_file_database

Answer (score 1):

If you had id[3]name[5]phone[6]

```
001Liz  882833
002Paul 892733
003John 927477
```

this is a fixed format file.